# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo; java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, adt

Sorry. Beginner at Java & programming.
I already searched up other answers but I just can't find whats wrong with my program.
By the way: NullPointerException means that somewhere in the program its using a variable with null as its value, right?

Main activity code:

```
package z_industries.theomnipotentbutton.theomnipotentbuttonfull;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


//initialize Log string
final public static String MTAG = "Main Activity";

//initialize variables
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
//private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button playButton;
public int selectedPlayer = 0;

//initialize intent for opening game activity
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //onCreate random stuff
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(MTAG, "MainActivity Start");

    /*//Initialize database
    SQLiteDatabase playerDB;
    PlayerDB dbhelper = new PlayerDB (this);
    playerDB = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();*/

    //create new function
    addListenerOnButton();

    //log
    Log.i(MTAG, "onCreate done");

}

//create the menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//function to activate button
public void addListenerOnButton (){

    //get each button
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.playerChoice);
    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick (View V){

            //get which button is selected 
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            //find out which button is selected using ID
            if (radioButton.getId() == 0x7f090006){
                selectedPlayer = 1;
                Log.i(MTAG, "Selected Player 1");
            }
            else if (radioButton.getId() == 0x7f090007){
                selectedPlayer = 2;
                Log.i(MTAG, "Selected Player 2");
            }
            else if (radioButton.getId() == 0x7f090008){
                selectedPlayer = 3;
                Log.i(MTAG, "Selected Player 3");
            }
            else {
                selectedPlayer = -1;
                Log.i(MTAG, "Error on radio button id");
            }

            //activate game activity
            startActivity(intent);

            /*public void startGame(View V){

            }*/
        }
    } );
}

/*@Override
public void openGame (View V){

}*/
```

}

Manifest File code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="z_industries.theomnipotentbutton.theomnipotentbuttonfull"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="z_industries.theomnipotentbutton.theomnipotentbuttonfull.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="GameActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ComicActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="BaseActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

BaseActivity, ComicActivity and GameActivity are literally empty except for essentials.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For Java questions that have an exception, always include the stack trace; it tells you exactly which statement caused the exception, and sometimes under what circumstances. For desktop applications, this is printed on the terminal, and for Android, it's in LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
  Intent intent; // declare it as instance vairable
```

Then in `onCreate`

```
 intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
```

Activity context is available in onCreate of activity. You can't use `this` before that.

Also you can do all your initializations of view's in `onCreate`.

Comment: If still issues remains please post ur log cat.

Comment: @sush pls post it below the op.

Comment: @sush question posted

Answer (score 0):

replace following

```
<activity
    android:name="GameActivity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="ComicActivity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="BaseActivity">
</activity>
```

with this

```
<activity
    android:name=".GameActivity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ComicActivity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".BaseActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: dot required in activity tag for name attribute. its basically relative path with package name

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thanks. I never knew this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize intent for opening game activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
```

**change this line to**

```
Intent intent;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
     ....
}
......
```